# How to disable progress bar in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am making HTTP communications with Axios in my Nuxt JS Project. When I send a request, a bar appears at the top of the page. How can I turn this off?

Also: How can I do if I want to edit this instead of closing it? (Color, Thickness)

Comment: This is a quality of life feature for your end users on slow connection devices. I do recommend not disabling it.

Comment: I put this manually where requests are made. (Progressbar). My client wants it like this ¯|_(**)_| ¯

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the progress bar with this, in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  loading: false
}
```

For any more info, check this link: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-loading#disable-the-progress-bar

You could also override it with your own CSS if you need it, inspect the element.